# Why does this Form redirect to the wrong file?

Tags: html, forms

I am creating login menu for my Admin panel. The login menu was called `login.php`, but then I changed it to `index.php`. I changed the action from `login.php` to `index.php`, but when I click the login button it still goes to `login.php`, which does not exist.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Cache-problems? Sure you are saving and using the correct file? (Check the console/code-view in your browser). Empty cache in your browser, or try a different browser, and see what happens

Comment: Sounds like a cookie problem. If you're on Chrome, you can push Ctrl+Shift+F5 to do a hard refresh of the page.

Comment: I am using correct file because if i change something in my login form i visually see the changes. And when i set my action for example to register page <form action="../../register.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off"> it load register page. But when i change it back to index it tries to load login.php

Answer (score 0):

I Recreated my form and now it works flawlessly, Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="Rform" method="post" action="authentication.php">
    <!-- Your input tags etc -->
    <!-- 'authentication.php' file to which redirect -->
</form>
```

Recreate file 'index.php' if you still got error or delete the previous file 'login.php'.